# Get button html part using regex(preg_match_all)

Tags: php, regex

Hello below is my html

```
$testHtml ='<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 190px;">
         <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Ottoman" href="">Ottoman</a></h2>
          <div class="price-box">
               <span id="product-price-51" class="regular-price">
               <span class="price">$299.99</span></span>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
               <div class="rating-box">
                  <div style="width:69%" class="rating"></div>
               </div>
              <span class="amount"><a onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href=''; return false;" href="#">4 Review(s)</a></span>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
                  <button onclick="setLocation('')" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
                  <ul class="add-to-links">
                       <li><a class="link-wishlist" href="">Add to Wishlist</a></li>
                       <li><span class="separator">|</span><a class="link-compare" href="/">Add to Compare</a></li>
                  </ul>
          </div>
     </div>';
```

I want only button tag like below

```
         <button onclick="setLocation('')" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

what is preg_match_all expression

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)?

Comment: It's very bad idea to use RegExp for HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: is it possible by using zend_dom_query?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
$pattern = '/(<button.*)/';
$result = preg_match($html, $pattern);
```